# Usage of 'Thank God' or 'Jesus Christ' as slang

Tags: slang, colloquialisms

Would the use of 'Thank God' or 'Jesus Christ' in a non-religious context be considered colloquial?

Example: "Thank God that's over"

The definition of colloquial I found was: used in ordinary or familiar conversation; not formal or literary.

I just want to be sure, thank you.

Comment: Yes, it would.  "Jesus Christ" and "God" are purely religious terms.  Using them in a slang context is considered colloquial, and if you are religious—blasphemy.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that those usages were slang though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the expressions are often used colloquially as interjections:

***[Thank God](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thank) (godness or  heavens)***

> - are set phrases used as an expression of relief:
>
>   - *thank God no one was badly injured*
>   - *the station survived just fine, thank heavens.*

(ODO)

> - These ejaculations originally expressed gratitude to divine providence but ***today tend to be used in a more casual way.***  [c. 1200]

(AHD)

***[Jesus Christ](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/jesus-christ_2)*** is also used colloquially as an interjection , but its usage may sound offensive as suggested by the following source:

> - used for expressing surprise or anger. *This use of the name Jesus Christ is offensive to many Christians.*'

(MacMillan Dictionary)